# Alert isn't working in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use an alert in my scripts but nothing is happening and I'm not sure why. I've using the exact code found in the Google Documentation but must be missing something. Any idea why I don't see the alert with the code below?

```js
function alertTest() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Working?');
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine for me. Copied the same code and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, so the function may not be getting triggered.  Add a `Logger.log('test ran!');` statement, and VIEW the LOG to see if anything printed to the LOG.  If nothing printed to the LOG, then the function never got triggered.  If there is an error that is killing your code, it should show up in the VIEW, EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT log.

Comment: I am manually triggering the function and have tested the function with a log as well. I can see the log, but never the alert.

Comment: It took a very long time for the alert to show up in my sheet.  There was a "dismiss" message for a long time.  I'm not sure why it took so long to run.  Try running that code in an 'onOpen()` function and refresh the sheet in the browser.

Comment: It seems like the issue was related to an error in the spreadsheet. I started getting a 'Service Error' on my previously working scripts, which I made no changes to. I duplicated the spreadsheet which got rid of the service error and then the alert started working too. I don't know why the service error was occurring, but it seems to be an issue many people have with no real explanation. Thanks for your help, Sandy.

Comment: There is a site to report issues. [Apps Script Issues Official Site](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)